# How to install and use rpy2 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, r, ubuntu, rpy2

I am trying to use Python to call R through rpy2. I am working on Ubuntu 15.10. I have installed Python 3.5.1 as part of Anaconda 2.4.1 (64bit), R and rpy2 version 2.7.6. When I tried $ python -m 'rpy2.tests' on the terminal, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thirsty/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 170, in    _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/thirsty/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/thirsty/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/tests.py",   line 23, in <module>
    import rpy2.tests_rpy_classic
  File "/home/thirsty/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/tests_rpy_classic.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rpy2.rpy_classic as rpy
  File "/home/thirsty/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rpy_classic.py", line 5, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as ri
  File "/home/thirsty/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import *
ImportError: /home/thirsty/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libreadline.so.6: undefined symbol: PC
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The versions of python, rpy2 are fine. Probably the command $ python -m 'rpy2.tests' may not be right way of testing rpy2. After starting python shell, when I typed import rpy2.robjects as robjects it worked without any errors and I was able to read files using R.

Comment: Indeed, `rpy2` is a module to be used inside a python `.py` script like any others: pandas, numpy, lxml, csv, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My server is not Ubuntu, but CentOS release 6.6 (Final). I solved this problem with this way, I think you can find corresponding file in Ubuntu.

```
cp /lib64/libreadline.so.6 ~/anaconda3/lib/libreadline.so.6
```

Done. Good luck.

But the way, if you can not install rpy2 and system tell you you need install Cython, then

```
pip uninstall Cython
pip install Cython
```

Good luck Again

Again, don't install Anaconda2 and Anaconda3 in your server at the same time, just use any one of them and then change the environment.